# Constructor injection affecting basic tests issue

Tags: angular, angular6

I have Angular6 project with following constructor in component:

```
constructor(@Inject('httpClient')private httpClient: HttpClient) {
}
```

It however may be affecting results of component-generated tests(e.g. "should create the app") with message related to:

```
Error: StaticInjectorError(DynamicTestModule)[httpClient]: 
StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[httpClient]: 
NullInjectorError: No provider for httpClient!
```

I have already tried importing HttpClientModule and also HttpClientTestingModule but it did not resolve issue.
Code related to describing component:

```
describe('AppComponent', () => {
beforeEach(async(() => {
TestBed.configureTestingModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
        ],
  imports: [
    FormsModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    HttpClientTestingModule
  ]
}).compileComponents();
}));
```

What steps can I take to get rid of the error message?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case you are facing constructor related testing issue and there is message involving InjectorError you can add imports with configureTestingModule.

Example:

```
TestBed.configureTestingModule({
imports: [
  HttpClientModule
]
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to mock the service. 
First, you create the dummy service :

```
class MockHttpClient { }
```

Then, in the `TestBed providers`, instead of `HttpClient`, you use the mocked service.

```
providers: [         
    { provide: HttpClient, useClass: MockHttpClient },
]
```

This way, you won't have to implement all the dependencies of the service.
Of course, you won't be able to use the real `HttpClient` functions, but that shouldn't be a problem as you should only test the component and not the service here.